# SQL Query to fetch complete order details according to product name and SKU

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to fetch order detail data from sql query in which i want product name child categories and sku

I try the following query for fetching orders by product name

```
select
p.order_id,
p.order_item_id,
p.order_item_name,
p.order_item_type,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_product_id' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as productID,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_qty' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Qty,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_product_sku' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as ProducrSKU,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_variation_id' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as variationID,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_total' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as lineTotal,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_subtotal_tax' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as subTotalTax,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_tax' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Tax,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_tax_class' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as taxClass,
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_subtotal' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as subtotal
from
wp_woocommerce_order_items as p,
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as pm
 where order_item_type = 'line_item' and
 p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id
 group by
p.order_item_id
```

now i need to add product sku in it and some categories.

Comment: Share sample data and expected output.

Comment: need a query to find orders according to product name and SKUs and want some product categories in it